# Model is not tightly coupled with my app

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am building android app by using Tensor flow for Android using this tutorial "https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#3"
Now I want to change the Model, for another set of image, but I don't want to do any change into Android app. How can we implement this?

Comment: Maybe make the demo project search for the model files in some downloaded folder instead of in the apk?

Comment: but Tensor flow SDK api's like "TensorFlowInferenceInterface" are looking for file in Assets, and I am not getting any other method into SDK, which is picking files from another location.

Comment: It isn't possible without a change in the code, since the model asset file is hardcoded. But you can easily just pass a file to the TensorFlowInferenceInterface as done here https://github.com/Qualeams/Android-Face-Recognition-with-Deep-Learning-Library/blob/dbe92113b180798571383edd377f9ab0f9b5d099/facerecognitionlibrary/src/main/java/ch/zhaw/facerecognitionlibrary/Recognition/TensorFlow.java#L74 or replace the asset model file

Comment: I was looking for a option to place model file other then assets folder inside application. I don't want to change mobile app, when model file is getting change. Because in case of minor change in model or addition of few image into model, should not require to change my application, as it will be another task to share APK with all users of my company.

Answer (score 0):

I you want to deploy your model separately from the app, you can download it from a server and save it in the file system.

Then just pass the file path to the InferenceInterface. E.g.:

```
String folder_path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/.models";
String model_name = "model.pb";
new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(getAssets(), folder_path + "/" + model_name);
```

This implementation of TensorFlowInferenceInterface will check for the file https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/25d275280dfb163674f81c7681c2c1d34545a155/tensorflow/contrib/android/java/org/tensorflow/contrib/android/TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java#L76